# gettting a TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting - I know where the error is but I don't understand how to correct it

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in pass_tmp:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        t = ord(i)
        t = t + rot7
        rotated_7 = chr(t
        decrypted += i.replace(i, rotated_7)

    else:
        t = ord(i)
        t = t + rot9
        rotated_9 = chr(t)
        decrypted += i.replace(i, rotated_9)

return decrypted
```

I am a learner of Python and this is an exercise that I'm doing during learning.

When running the code I am receiving the following error message "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" while referencing to the "if i % 2 == 0:" line in the code.

It works as it should until I add the "if i % 2 == 0:" line and have added the else code block.
what i am trying to achieve is to separate the code to do different decoding depend on if the index of pass_tmp even or odd which "if i % 2 == 0" should take care of, it has worked before in every other exercise that I have had to use it but now it is not.

Comment: are your `pass_tmp` a string?

Comment: Yes, it is a string

Comment: What do you suppose  `'2'`%2 is gooing to do? String % 2 ?  Where is the closing ) in `rotated_7 = chr(t`? Where is a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pass_tmp` is a string and you need both the character and its index you might want to use `for i, char in enumerate(pass_tmp)` that way, `i` will be the index and `char` the character you can operate with. It would end up like this:

```py
for i, char in enumerate(pass_tmp):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        t = ord(char)
        t = t + rot7
        rotated_7 = chr(t)
        decrypted += char.replace(char, rotated_7)

    else:
        t = ord(char)
        t = t + rot9
        rotated_9 = chr(t)
        decrypted += char.replace(char, rotated_9)

return decrypted
```

You are getting a typeError because the operation `i % 2 == 0` is trying to get the modulus of dividing a string with an integer

Also since you are iterating one character at a time doing `decrypted += i.replace(i, rotated_x)` is not necessary, you can optimize a little adding the new variable directly like `decrypted += rotated_x`, something like:

```py
for i, char in enumerate(pass_tmp):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        t = ord(char)
        t = t + rot7
        rotated_7 = chr(t)
        decrypted += rotated_7

    else:
        t = ord(char)
        t = t + rot9
        rotated_9 = chr(t)
        decrypted += rotated_9

return decrypted
```